# jquery accordion with delete icon on right

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[image]

For hours I have been trying to add an extra icon to right side of the jQuery accordion item header. I have the following code but there are 3 problems:

**1)** When collapsed my item header has 0 height
**2)** The position of the following item title is off, for example "Section 2" in my example.
**3)** There is an arrow displaying in my item content
**4)** I want to avoid hard coded sizes, and positions as much as possible

My code(you can download all necessary files from here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12893123/accordion.zip) is like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="jquery-ui.custom.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(function() {
    var stop = false;
    $( "#accordion div" ).click(function( event ) {
        if ( stop ) {
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
            stop = false;
        }
    });
    $( "#accordion" )
        .accordion({
            header: "> div > div"
        })
        .sortable({
            axis: "y",
            handle: "div",
            stop: function() {
                stop = true;
            }
        });
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
div.div1 {
    background: red;
    position:relative;
}
div.div2 {
    background: green;
    float: left;
}
div.div3 {
    background: yellow;
    float: right;
}
div.div4 {
    clear: both;
}

</style>

    <div id="accordion">
        <div>
            <div class="div1"><div class="div2"><a href="#">Section 1</a></div><div class="div3"><img src="delete_icon.gif"></img></div></div>
            <div class="div4">
                <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div><a href="#">Section 2</a></div>
            <div>
                <p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div><a href="#">Section 3</a></div>
            <div>
                <p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis. Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui. </p>
                <ul>
                    <li>List item one</li>
                    <li>List item two</li>
                    <li>List item three</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div><a href="#">Section 4</a></div>
            <div>
                <p>Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia mauris vel est. </p><p>Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution. I just added `overflow: auto;` to `div1` and all problems fixed.